# Selenium 2: How to check that server is running and stop the server?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

With Selenium 1 there was the possibility to enter a URL to stop the server:

http://:/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDown

Is there a similar way in Selenium 2?

I tried the following URL to check whether the server is running:

http://:/wd/hub/

but that only returns an HTTP ERROR 503 (service unavailable).
Is there any other URL I can access to verify that the server is running?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The Selenium server in 2.0 contains all of the same code that was in Selenium 1, so checking for, say, `http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=getLogMessages` will test for the existence of the server. Likewise, you can issue `http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer` to shut the server down.

There was recently a new `/status` URL added to the [JSON wire protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) used by the 2.0 parts of the server, but I'm not certain it's been implemented in the remote server just yet. This would be accessed by `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/status`, when implemented. Additionally, there isn't yet an equivalent shutdown URL in the wire protocol.

Comment: +1 for the status URL, but your getLogMessages URL fails utterly on my machine, and doesn't seem to jibe with the docs you linked too.

Comment: That's because the docs I linked to are "used by the 2.0 parts od the server." The getLogMessages URL is a 1.0 construct.

Comment: In version 3, shutdown has been removed. Apparently one can run the standalone server in node mode with a LifecycleServlet which makes it behave effectively as the standalone server and then you can use a different URL to shut it down (http://127.0.0.1:4444/extra/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown) - see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2852#issuecomment-250841027  HOWEVER, I gather that even that option may be removed in future, leaving a "kill" or equivalent as the only option.

Comment: Just to leave an idea about how to shutdown the server here that worked for me, i.e. use the port to indentify the process id and then kill it:

kill $(lsof -i :4444 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}')