# Running Selenium 1 RC commands against Selenium 2 server

Tags: selenium, phpunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get Selenium 1 commands working against a Selenium 2 server.  From what I've read, the Selenium server stand-alone jar will also accept Selenium 1 RC-type calls.  For example, if I have Selenium 2 running on selenium.server:4444, I should be able to call:

http://selenium.server:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=getLogMessages

and get a valid response.  Instead, I get a 500 error.  This seemed to be explained here:

[Selenium 2: How to check that server is running and stop the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517501/selenium-2-how-to-check-that-server-is-running-and-stop-the-server)

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something here?  We are running the Selenium extension of PHPUnit, so we cannot use the Java bindings for Selenium 2 (which I understand have built-in reverse compatibilty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest PHPUnit version, there was a bug in earlier versions causing problems with Selenium server.

The node should be started with role node as well.

Comment: We're running a hub with several nodes for testing.  I'm sending commands to the hub.  Upgrading is a good idea, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Upgrading PHPUnit did the trick, appears older PHPUnit extension was using GET rather than POST https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/commit/1d0f9e80c17ee8e0345be5eba308a93d8d557f66 .  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you start the Selenium Server with Java?

If not, try it.

If I understand your question right, your server isn't starting.

Comment: Actually, the server is starting fine and responds to selenium 2 commands using web driver, just not selenium 1.