# how to check if selenium server is running?

Tags: bash, selenium, jenkins

how can I check if selenium server is running and start selenium if it is not running. I get the error connection refused often when integrated selenium tests into jenkins. Obviously, I want to give selenium a chance to get started because running my tests. What's the proper bash command to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

Would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6546732/6606196) be of help to you?  Basically it recommends you hit a url (e.g. http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver?cmd=getLogMessages) to see if the server is running.