# How to check if a remote Selenium Grid hub is executing tests?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We are currently building a web interface for our manual QA team to be able to run Selenium tests, which are executed on remote machines via Selenium Grid.

I am looking for some way to remotely check if the Selenium Grid is *currently* executing any tests so I can then queue any additional runs sent to the Grid from the web interface until the previous test execution completes. This will ensure we avoid overloading the grid with too many simultaneous test runs.

I have searched through StackOverflow and read through the Selenium documentation to see if there were any commands that can be used to check for this, but came up empty.

Comment: @JeffC

"I have searched through StackOverflow and read through the Selenium documentation to see if there were any commands that can be used to check for this, but came up empty."

This is a question whose answer was NOT obvious to me, and has not been asked previously on this forum that I could find. I would imagine stating that I had searched for the answer would indicate that I have done the legwork prior to asking. Not sure what else you are needing here.

Comment: A quick search gives me the top two results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517501/selenium-2-how-to-check-that-server-is-running-and-stop-the-server and https://allabouttestautomation.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/useful-selenium-grid-commands-to-query-status-and-shutdown-hub-nodes/ which looks like something you are looking for but you didn't mention that you've looked at them or dismissed them, etc.

Comment: Generally people state that they've searched all over but a quick google search returns a number of useful links so documenting what terms you've searched, what you have looked at and dismissed saves us a lot of time trying to guess... which is what I originally stated. I seriously doubt you are the first person to ask this question. You should go into any Q on SO with this in mind and assume you aren't the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to manage tests queue by yourself. Selenium grid and nodes have it in place. So for reducing overload on each nodes there are some configurations available. We have `maxSession` and `maxInstance` parameters.

`maxSession` - the maximum number of browsers that can run in parallel on the node
`maxInstance` - the maximum number of same browser instances that can run in parallel on the node.

F.e. maxSession = 3, maxInstance = 2. You can have 2 firefox + 1 chrome

You didnt mention what is your selenium driver version. so lets say its the newest `3.x.x`. You can create `node-config.json` file and store there this parameters.

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": "2",#settings per browser
        }
    ],
    "maxSession": "3", #settings per node
}
```

To start the node:

```
java -jar /path_to_driver/serve.jar -role node -hub HUB_ADDRESS -nodeConfig /path_to_node_config/node-config.json
```

So when you want to run new test - grid will register it and will wait for a free node. So it can keep a stack for you

Also you can use bash command `parallel` and create an array of your tests and then run it in a parallel way. Lets say 5 jobs in parallel.

`parallel --jobs 5 -k --gnu ::: "${arrayToRun[@]}"`

More about [Selenium configuration](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes-by-json)
More about run tests in [parallel](http://zalas.eu/running-behat-in-parallel-with-selenium-grid/)

Answer (score 6):

You can see this details in grid console. For example if you are running the hub in local machine then the console URL is http://localhost:4444/grid/console.  If you are running the grid hub on another machine then replace the local host with IP or hostname of the grid hub machine in the console URL.

There are many ways to know it.

1. If any of the node is occupied by test execution then the browser icon will be greyed out.(some times, you have to refresh the page to get status).
2. Otherwise if you mouse over on any browser icon in the console it will show the session ID if it is executing any test.
3. In selenium hub command line window logs. It will list out available nodes in a frequent interval.

[image]